# Reduce the length of a feature vector for comparison

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, dimension, reduction

I have a problem, where several different objects are each described by a vector of real numbers, between 0 and 100, and a length (dimension) of 1000 elements.

Then I want to compare a new vector of equal characteristics with the set of vectors above, to find the most similar, with the Mahalanobis distance.

My question is:

How can I reduce the length of the vectors to the N most relevant elements (say, 100 of the 1000), without affecting too much the quality of the answers found, ie, the distance does not vary too much?

Remember that each vector is a description of a different object, unrelated to others.

I thought about using PCA, but after studying it, I saw that I needed at least two samples per object, or so I understood.

Any idea? In case of coding, I´m using C++, OpenCV

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also ask on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ for the theory, and then ask here for the actual programming ;)

Comment: Some keywords I know: [VLAD or Fisher vector](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/encodings.html). On a same topic: [Aggregating local descriptors into a compact image representation](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2010/JDSP10/jegou_compactimagerepresentation.pdf)